# How can I capture click events/signals of a QGraphicsSvgItem

Tags: qt, events, svg, click, mouse

I'm new to Qt. How can I capture click events/signals of a QGraphicsSvgItem inside a QGraphicsScene? I have the following code:

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
QGraphicsSvgItem *svgItem = new QGraphicsSvgItem(":/SomeGraphic.svg");
svgItem->scale(0.1, 0.1);
svgItem->setPos(-200,-200);
scene->addItem(svgItem);
```

Is it possible to connect() the click() signal of svgItem to a slot?

Answer (score 3):

`QGraphicsSvgItem` hasn't a click() signal.

There are many ways to capture mouse events on a QGraphicsItem:

1. You can subclass `QGraphicsSvgItem` and implement `void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event)`. See [QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#mousePressEvent)
2. You can install an event filter on the `QGraphicsScene` or on the `QGraphicsView` and intercept the mouse events and see if the mouse is pressed on your item. See [QObject::installEventFilter()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter)
3. Also you can install an event filter directly on the `QGraphicsSvgItem`. See [QGraphicsItem::installSceneEventFilter()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#installSceneEventFilter)
4. You can subclass `QGraphicsScene` and implement `mousePressEvent()`. See [QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#mousePressEvent)
5. You can subclass `QGraphicsView` and implement `mousePressEvent()`. See [QWidget::mousePressEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent)